# Issues with Å, Ä, and Ö (for other users) when coding in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem coding in another language than English (when the input is in another language). For example, it is important to be able to write "LÅNG" and then use that input for my macros. However, when I have sent this to other computers, the "Å" get distorted and the macro does not work. Is there a way to fix this?

I guess I could write code that translate "Lång" to "Lang" etc., but even the code going is already distorted:/ What to do?

Edit: Code example (words have been edited):

```
MsgBox "Område saknas"   'free text-an error message prompting user action. This got completely distorted

Dim ColumnProjekt as String
ColumnProjekt = "Höst" .   'This changed when to something difference resulting in many, many errors in my other code.

Select Case Tidshorisont 'this is declared as a string and could contain "Lång"
    Case "Lång"
```

Comment: *it is important to be able to write "LÅNG"* And what problem are you having? You can save that text into an string variable.Something like `str = "LÅNG"` should work for you

Comment: can you share the code ?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, it is very important to be able to write words like "Lång". I don't think that is the problem, unless the problem lies with my function that collects the value? The function below is one of my function that loops through each row in my table and retrieves values from specific columns. I'll post this below. Otherwise I have them all declared as string variables

Comment: Function RetrieveTidshorisont(currentRow As ListRow, ColumnTidshorisont As String) As range
    Set Tidshorisont = Intersect(currentRow.range, currentRow.Parent.ListColumns(ColumnTidshorisont).range)
End Function

Comment: @Jo.lass, please see my edited question

Comment: Treat user-facing strings as data, not code, and all will be fine. You can store the user-facing string values in a table on a hidden worksheet. A VBA `String` can hold the accented characters; it's the VBIDE's ANSI encoding that's wrecking it all.

Comment: Great! I'll combine this with the soln below and I'll be all set. Thank you!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, if I have understood you correctly would it work if I store "ÅÄÖ" in a string named "TEST" before using, for example, msgbox TEST? If so, I could just apply the same logic when evaluating user-facing string values in Case/loops etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a great article about Unicode, explaining why the umlauts are changed on other computers:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Long story short - it is not a bug and there is no excuse to write code in German, naming variables in German (or in any other language but English). In the documentation, you may write in German (or in any other language).

If the idea is to write the `MsgBox()` in German, then the correct way to do it in Excel is something like this:

```
MsgBox tblSettings.Range("C5")
```

And in `tblSettings.Range("C5")` write the string. **However**, if it is opened in a computer, which does not support German as a regional system language (probably about 99% of the world PCs), then the following actions should be carried out by the user:

- Clock And Region (search in start menu)
- Region (link)
- Administrative (tab)
- Change system locale (button)
- Current System Locale - Germany (drop down)

Or as a workaround - write "Laeng" and relax - it would work.

[image]

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, thank you once again. Very informative! I have one additional question though (just for clarification). For example, the company runs everything in non-english and it was stated very important to be able to type "Lång" which is "Long" speaking about time horizon when adding new projects. Hence, words such as "Lång" will (hopefully unless I can argue that it is not possible) will appear in my table. But if my code can read "Lång" and correctly translate it to "Laeng" when doing calculations then it is no problems at all

Comment: That said, (and I'll now move on to read the link you posted) can I argue that it is not possible unless the actions listed by you are performed beforehand by the user?

Comment: @OmgAllCaps thanks, but this is all Vityata's work, I only changed but a single character in this post ;-)

Comment: oh my bad! @Vityata - thank you so much for your input! and MathieuGuindon - I owe you more than a few thanks for things in the past so:)

Comment: @OmgAllCaps - create an additional worksheet, which would act as a dictionary to English. Then with `=Index(Match(),Match())` or `=vlookup()` or something similar, it would refer to the correct naming of the column. Do not try tell the people to rename the whole Excel file to English, noone would be happy with this solution.

Comment: @Vityata, thank you again - brilliant! That will for sure take care of the problem I'm having. Love this community

Comment: @Vityata, my apologies but perhaps I could bother you with a follow-up question? I cannot seem to get it to work. Let say you have a range consisting of 10 cells, where cell #8 consist of the value "Å Ä Ö". How would you go about looping through this range with VBA code? I assume there have to be some kind of "validation" before each cell enters the loop so that "Å" could be translated into "A" etc. beforehand. I'm clueless how to do this evaluation before assigning it to a variable (String, Variant, Range etc.). Perhaps you could throw me another bone?

Comment: Possibly, it would seem that the "Å, Ä, and Ö" get correctly moved form the user input sheet into another sheet (my database). Hence, words such as "Höst" does indeed show up in my database. I'm thinking that perhaps I could use a "Conditional format" in my database to convert all "Höst" into "Host". Would that be a good soln?

Comment: @OmgAllCaps - enjoy - https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-how-to-avoiding-naming-variables-with-non-latin-alphabet-special-letters/

Comment: @Vityata, that is wonderful - indeed enjoyable! I'll combine this with the below function (in case you are interested). Thank you!

Comment: Function IsLatin(Str As String) As Boolean
IsLatin = True
For i = 1 To Len(Str)
    IsLatin = IsLatin And Abs(AscW(Mid(Str, i, 1)) - 64) < 64
Next i
End Function

Comment: @OmgAllCaps - if it works for you, it is OK. But probably it would be faster to search whether the whole word is present in the dictionary worksheet, I guess.