# Excel VBA special characters in literal strings being changed

Tags: excel, vba, non-ascii-characters

I have a macro that inserts a few literal strings into an excel file to be converted to a txt file. These literal strings have some German special characters. The macro works as expected for colleagues, except for one particular Greek colleague (other Greek colleagues have no issue).

When that specific colleague reviews the macro's code in the visual basic editor, the German special characters are changed to Greek characters. If it were just visual, I wouldn't care, but this also changes the content of the txt file that is generated.

Example:

> correct string = "Empfänger"
>
> incorrect string = "Empfδnger"

I tried:

- googling but the keywords make getting proper results difficult
- changing the language settings in region settings of the control panel
- changing the language setting in excel options.

It is almost certainly related to regional settings, but I have been unsuccessful in finding what specific options it is.
Found some posts that directed me to Language for non-unicode programs settings, but that seemingly wasn't the issue.
The `Region > Administrative > Language` for non-unicode programs is showing Greek for the user, but it also shows as Greek for the user in which there is no issue.

If anyone can help me track down the issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: There is another post with a similar question, that has an accepted answer that may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272508/issues-with-%C3%85-%C3%84-and-%C3%96-for-other-users-when-coding-in-vba

Comment: yeah I also wanted to mention that you should check the encoding of the generated textfile. Maybe compare the encoding of your text file with the encoding of your colleagues text file.

Comment: Encoding of txt file is correct, i added the encoding in the savas vba code, xlUnicodetext.

Comment: @5202456 I tried to understand what was discussed in that link, but not sure if I was fully able to follow. My main concern with that post is that it sounded more global whereas my situation is only impacting 1 person.

Comment: If the problem affect only one user, maybe check the encoding settings on their computer and compare to the settings on other users' machines

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Where to check though?

Comment: I would start with the software use to open the text file (and also the method used to open/import it)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad The issue is not related to the txt file. The user observes the character change in excel visual basic editor.

Comment: The character change in the VBE is purely visual (i.e. the same code points being displayed differently) because the VBE uses a locale dependent 8-bit character encoding to display the code. Since you have already located the relevant setting (`Region > Administrative > Language for non-Unicode programs`) I'm surprised you still get different results. Did you change this setting? If yes, did you restart the pc after the change? If yes, can you share the affected code?

Comment: @GWD It isn't just visual, as the characters are in literal string mappings. Which are being inserted in the sheet as a mapping translation. I was not able to change this non -Unicode setting as my company has it locked to only admins, though testing the setting was not necessary as the user has the same setting as another user with no issues.

Comment: The code is a simple if statement mapping. If cell value = 10 then cell value = string

Comment: You can check the binary contents of the string using the [StringToHex](https://github.com/guwidoe/VBA-StringTools/blob/6a941b54a8027c975875446b1bde90648e833ddb/src/LibStringTools.bas#LL984C1-L984C1) function from my repository. There are also many other tools available in the repo that you might find helpful to deal with such issues, unfortunately it's still an early version and not much documentation is available apart from comments above the function declarations.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out and see if it can be a workaround for my issue.

Comment: @GWD The function from your repository worked for me, but did not for the user with the issue. The characters became their non accented latin counterparts. Not really sure how that is possible. I am at a loss.

Comment: @ManouilGioulountas, which function are you talking about now? I think I know what is happening, I'm just surprised the VBE is not affected by the `Region > Administrative > Language for non-Unicode programs` setting in a consistent way between you and your colleague. Basically, the VBE uses an 8-bit encoding for the source code files. When executed, the compiler takes the string literals from the source code and transcodes from the system settings specific 8-bit codepage to UTF-16 encoded Unicode. I thought the setting determining this conversion is the aforementioned one...

Comment: The workaround you can use is to avoid all non-ASCII characters in string literals in the source code since the first 7 bits (ASCII) are locale independent and will behave consistently. I will post an answer with an easy-to-use workaround.

Comment: @GWD I would immediately accept the proposal to put the strings elsewhere, if code didn't work for all but 1 person. There is a setting somewhere that breaks how excel reads these characters, I just don't know which one and it has me very curious.
For now, the user is doing a fine and replace on the end file.
I am also looking at inserting these strings in a hidden sheet to be read by the macro instead of the strings being in the code itself.

Comment: @ManouilGioulountas I'm more surprised that it shows the `"ä"` for any user with greek system locale as the normal behavior is definitely `"δ"` in that case. I just changed my system locale to greek and it's now displayed as `"δ"` in the VBE.

Comment: @GWD I missed you previous question about which function i was using. It was the one you linked stringtohex and hextostring counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

As you are already aware, the Visual Basic Editor is a non-Unicode app and uses a system-locale-dependent 8-bit character encoding (ANSI) for the source code. The string literals in the source code are then transcoded from this locale-specific non-Unicode codepage to UTF-16 at some point before or during compilation.

As I can not reproduce the behavior you are describing

> ...it also shows as Greek for the user in which there is no issue.

I can only offer a workaround in this answer, because as far as I know (and as per my testing) the thing you describe as issue is the expected behavior:

```vb
correctString = "Empfänger" 'Expected for users with e.g. German system-locale
incorrectString = "Empfδnger" 'Expected for users with Greek system-locale
```

If you use string literals in code (for which there are definitely many legitimate use cases) only characters from the ASCII codepoint range will behave consistently across all system locales.

You can therefore work around this problem by using some functions from my library [VBA-StringTools](https://github.com/guwidoe/VBA-StringTools).

The functions you need are the following:

```vb
'Replaces all occurences of unicode characters outside the codePoint range
'defined by maxNonEncodedCharCode with literals of the following formattings:
'   \uXXXX      for characters inside the basic multilingual plane
'   \uXXXXXXXX  for characters outside the basic multilingual plane
'Where:
'   Xes are the digits of the codepoint in hexadecimal. (X = 0-9 or A-F)
Public Function EscapeUnicode(ByRef str As String, _
                     Optional ByVal maxNonEncodedCharCode As Long = &HFF) _
                              As String
    Dim codepoint As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long:          j = 1
    Dim result() As String: ReDim result(1 To Len(str))

    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        codepoint = AscW(Mid$(str, i, 1)) And &HFFFF&

        If codepoint >= &HD800& Then codepoint = AscU(Mid$(str, i, 2))

        If codepoint > &HFFFF& Then 'Outside BMP
            result(j) = "\u" & "00" & Right$("0" & Hex(codepoint), 6)
            i = i + 1
        ElseIf codepoint > maxNonEncodedCharCode Then 'BMP
            result(j) = "\u" & Right$("00" & Hex(codepoint), 4)
        Else
            result(j) = Mid$(str, i, 1)
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next i
    EscapeUnicode = Join(result, "")
End Function

#If Mac = 0 Then
'Replaces all occurences of unicode literals
'Accepts the following formattings `escapeFormat`:
' efPython = 1 … \uXXXX \u00XXXXXX   (4 or 8 hex digits, 8 for chars outside BMP)
' efRust   = 2 … \u{XXXX} \U{XXXXXX} (1 to 6 hex digits)
' efUPlus  = 4 … u+XXXX u+XXXXXX     (4 or 6 hex digits)
' efMarkup = 8 … &#ddddddd;          (1 to 7 decimal digits)
'Where:
'   - prefixes \u is case insensitive
'   - Xes are the digits of the codepoint in hexadecimal. (X = 0-9 or A-F/a-f)
'Example:
'   - "abcd &#97;u+0062\U0063xy\u{64}", efAll returns "abcd abcxyd"
'Notes:
'   - Avoid u+XXXX syntax if string contains literals without delimiters as it
'     can be misinterpreted if adjacent to text starting with 0-9 or a-f.
'   - This function can be slow for very long input strings with many
'     different literals
Private Function UnescapeUnicode(ByRef str As String, _
                        Optional ByVal allowSingleSurrogates As Boolean = False) _
                                 As String
    Const PATTERN_UNICODE_LITERALS As String = _
        "\\u00[01][0-9a-f]{5}|\\u[0-9a-f]{4}|" & _
        "\\u{[0-9a-f]{1,6}}|u\+[0-9a-f]{4,6}|&#\d{1,7};"
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = PATTERN_UNICODE_LITERALS
        Dim mc As Object: Set mc = .Execute(str)
    End With

    Dim match As Variant
    Dim codepoint As Long
    Dim dupeCheck As Collection
    Set dupeCheck = New Collection
    Dim isDuplicate As Boolean

    For Each match In mc
        Dim mv As String: mv = match.value
        On Error Resume Next
        dupeCheck.Add 1, mv
        isDuplicate = Err.number <> 0
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not isDuplicate Then
            If Left$(mv, 1) = "&" Then
                codepoint = CLng(Mid$(mv, 3, Len(mv) - 3))
            Else
                If Mid$(mv, 3, 1) = "{" Then
                    codepoint = CLng("&H" & Mid$(mv, 4, Len(mv) - 4))
                Else
                    codepoint = CLng("&H" & Mid$(mv, 3))
                End If
            End If
            If codepoint < &H110000 Then
                If codepoint < &HD800& Or codepoint >= &HE000& _
                Or allowSingleSurrogates Then _
                    str = Replace(str, mv, ChrU(codepoint))
            End If
        End If
    Next match
    UnescapeUnicode = str
End Function
#End If

'Returns the given unicode codepoint as standard VBA UTF-16LE string
 Public Function ChrU(ByVal codepoint As Long, _
             Optional ByVal allowSingleSurrogates As Boolean = False) As String
    Const methodName As String = "ChrU"

    If codepoint < &H8000 Then Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Codepoint < -32768"
    If codepoint < 0 Then codepoint = codepoint And &HFFFF& 'Incase of uInt input

    If codepoint < &HD800& Then
        ChrU = ChrW$(codepoint)
    ElseIf codepoint < &HE000& And Not allowSingleSurrogates Then
        Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Range reserved for surrogate pairs"
    ElseIf codepoint < &H10000 Then
        ChrU = ChrW$(codepoint)
    ElseIf codepoint < &H110000 Then
        codepoint = codepoint - &H10000
        ChrU = ChrW$(&HD800& Or (codepoint \ &H400&)) & _
               ChrW$(&HDC00& Or (codepoint And &H3FF&))
    Else
        Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Codepoint outside of valid Unicode range."
    End If
End Function

'Returns a given characters unicode codepoint as long.
'Note: One unicode character can consist of two VBA "characters", a so-called
'      "surrogate pair" (input string of length 2, so Len(char) = 2!)
Public Function AscU(ByRef char As String) As Long
    AscU = AscW(char) And &HFFFF&
    If Len(char) > 1 Then
        Dim lo As Long: lo = AscW(Mid$(char, 2, 1)) And &HFFFF&
        If &HDC00& > lo Or lo > &HDFFF& Then Exit Function
        AscU = (AscU - &HD800&) * &H400& + (lo - &HDC00&) + &H10000
    End If
End Function
```

When developing the macro, you use the `EscapeUnicode` function to replace all Unicode characters outside the ASCII range with escape sequences. For the string in your question, you would put the following line into the immediate window:

```vb
?EscapeUnicode("Empfänger", 127) '127 is the last character in the ASCII range
```

which will return the escaped string `Empf\u00E4nger`.

In your actual code, you now use this string together with the `UnescapeUnicode` function:

```vb
correctString = UnescapeUnicode("Empf\u00E4nger")
```

The variable will now contain the correct string when inserted into a cell on the worksheet, regardless of system-locale.

Maybe this workaround is more suitable for you than creating a hidden sheet to read the string literals from.

Note that the function `UnescapeUnicode` provided in this answer only works on Windows because it uses regular expressions. The function from the GitHub repository supports MacOS and performs much better, so I'd recommend just adding the [LibStringTools](https://github.com/guwidoe/VBA-StringTools/blob/main/src/LibStringTools.bas) module to your project.

Comment: I will try this set of functions soon. Hopefully will work. This users computer is baffling me. I wish i could be on site to check myself.

Comment: @ManouilGioulountas, did you get a chance to try it out?

Comment: I have not. They are doing a find/replace for now since I was unable to track down the cause of the problem. They are not too concerned with finding a more complex solution.
Thank you for your time though.